# Custom Error Page in Production for .NET 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, custom-error-pages

I am trying to implement a custom 404 page in my .NET 5.0 for when the web app is in production. I have implemented the following in **Startup.cs**;

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            } 
            else
            {
                app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/{0}");
            } 
            ...
}
```

Linking to a simple **ErrorController**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        [Route("/Error/{statusCode}")]
        public IActionResult HttpStatusCodeHandler(int statusCode)
        {
            switch(statusCode)
            {
                case 404:
                    //ViewBag.ErrorMessage("Resource could not be found.");
                    break;
            }
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

and goes to **Error.cshtml** found in *Shared*.

This does nothing to remove the default `Status Code: 404; Not Found` page, but the page is accessible if I go to `localhost/Error/404` directly through url.

This is how I remember implementing this with previous versions of .NET, but now I'm unsure if I'm missing something or if the new .NET 5.0 has a new requirement for implementing the custom 404 page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: **launchSettings.json** Profile:

```
"Proj_prod": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
            }
        }
```

Comment: i believe you're just running app in development mode. Nothing  is wrong with the code

Comment: You can change the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT from Development to Production inside the Properties\LaunchSettings.json and test again. As Alexander Mokin said it is because you're testing int development environment.

Comment: @AlexanderMokin Sorry failed to mention that I already checked to ensure that ```"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"``` is set to ```"Production"```. Edited the question to include the launchSettings profile details just in case.

Comment: setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Production doesn't guarantee you're running the Proj_prod configuration. The default config is IISExpress. Put a breakpoint on the line app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/{0}"); and check if you're hitting it on startup.

Comment: @AlexanderMokin The breakpoint on app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects is being hit on startup. Just in case, I set IISExpress to Production as well and it produces the same result as with Proj_prod.

Comment: You can try to rebuild a new project. For me, setting the environment of `IIS Express` to `Production` and using your code will work well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay the actual code in question works as intended. A work partner added `app.UseStatusCodePages();` far later down the Configure which I didn't notice.

(Yes, it took 14 days. I've finally went back to this and just noticed.)

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have a correct route or if you are being redirected to `/Error/404` and then You can redirect the user to the custom 404

```
 [Route("/Error/{statusCode}")]
    public IActionResult HttpStatusCodeHandler(int? statusCode)
    {
        switch(statusCode.Value)
        {
            case 404:
                //ViewBag.ErrorMessage("Resource could not be found.");
                //TempData["Message"] = "Resource could not be found."
                return RedirectToAction("404");
                break;
        }
        return View("Error");
    }
```

PS: you can also use `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?statusCode={0}");` which would send the request parameter, not as a route

Comment: My issue is that when I input any junk url, I am not being redirected to /Error/_404_, it would simply remain in the junk url and output ```Status Code: 404; Not Found```. 
I have tried the above implementation just in case but there was no change to my issue. ```app.UseStatusCodeWithRedirect / app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute``` is being hit on startup.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you run your project `IIS Express`. for that you could not find your custom error page as expected. You should use  `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"` in your  `profile` in `launchsettings.json`.and it resolves your issue. just change your code like below.

```
//clarify

  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"   //add this
      }
    },
    "Proj_prod": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```